# Error 1822 en MySQL

Tags: mysql

me sale el error

> 1822 (Failed to add foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint "Res_Habitacion_part_FK" in the referenced table "habitacion") cuando trato de crear la tabla RESERVA.

El código completo es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CATEGORIA (
ID_Categoría CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
Descripción VARCHAR(150),
IVA TINYINT DEFAULT ' 21 '
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HOTEL (
Código CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
Nombre VARCHAR(30)UNIQUE,
Dirección VARCHAR(50),
Teléfono CHAR(9),
Año YEAR,
ID_Categoría CHAR(5),
CONSTRAINT Categoría_part_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID_Categoría) REFERENCES CATEGORIA(ID_Categoría) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HABITACION (
Código_Hotel CHAR(5), 
N_Habitación CHAR(3),
Tamaño VARCHAR(3),
Precio VARCHAR(4),
Tipo VARCHAR(10),
CONSTRAINT Habitacion_PK PRIMARY KEY (Código_Hotel,N_Habitación),
CONSTRAINT Hotel_part_FK FOREIGN KEY (Código_Hotel) REFERENCES HOTEL(Código) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CLIENTE (
DNI CHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
Nombre_cli VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Dirección VARCHAR(50),
Teléfono CHAR(9)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RESERVA (
Código_Hotel CHAR(5), 
N_Habitación CHAR(3),
DNI_Cliente CHAR(9),
Importe VARCHAR(4),
F_Inicio DATE,
F_Fin DATE,
CONSTRAINT Reserva_PK PRIMARY KEY (Código_Hotel,N_Habitación,DNI_Cliente,F_Inicio),
CONSTRAINT Res_Hotel_part_FK FOREIGN KEY (Código_Hotel) REFERENCES HOTEL(Código) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT Res_Habitacion_part_FK FOREIGN KEY (N_Habitación) REFERENCES HABITACION(N_Habitación) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT Res_Cliente_part_FK FOREIGN KEY (DNI_Cliente) REFERENCES CLIENTE(DNI) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que el error lo tienes aqui en la tabla HABITACION

**CONSTRAINT Habitacion_PK PRIMARY KEY (Código_Hotel,N_Habitación)**

estas creando una clave primaria compuesta......

y en la tabla RESERVA , aqui

**CONSTRAINT Res_Habitacion_part_FK FOREIGN KEY (N_Habitación) REFERENCES HABITACION(N_Habitación) ON DELETE CASCADE,**

estas indicando que coja la key N_Habitación cuando deberia ser "Código_Hotel,N_Habitación"

recuerda que solo puede haber una key, pero que una key puede estar compuesta por dos campos